# SQL - Two Columns into One Distinct Ordered Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table like this:

```
Col 1 | Col 2
-------------
   A  |  1
   A  |  2
   B  |  1
   C  |  1
   C  |  2
   C  |  3
```

How can I write a query to pull one column that looks like this --

```
Col 1 
------
  A
  1
  2
  B
  1
  C
  1
  2
  3
```

Comment: You want same order expected

Comment: `select col1 union select col2`

Comment: @TheGameiswar - `union all` is faster

Comment: @hogan :yes,thats true

Comment: @Hogan  he expected result is different order

Comment: @Chanukya -- interesting point -- I wonder what the rules are for order -- maybe it is order by col1 asc but put col2 after col1 then order by col2 asc.  seems possible.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT col1
FROM Some_Table_You_Did_Not_Name

UNION ALL

SELECT col2
FROM Some_Table_You_Did_Not_Name
```

If the order matters in your example then you want this:

```
WITH data AS
(
   SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1, col2) as RN
   FROM Some_Table_You_Did_Not_Name
)
SELECT col
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT col1 as col, RN, 1 as O
    FROM data

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT col2 as col, RN, 2 as O
    FROM data
) JC_IS_THAT_GUY
ORDER BY RN ASC, O ASC, col ASC
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti -- that is what I get for using db2 to much (which does not require the alias.)  -- I think my order is correct -- what is wrong?

Comment: Muscle memory thing.  I know.  :)

Comment: OK that was funny!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti -- thanks -- tho you deleted your comment so we are the only ones that get it.  I added the "O" column, I think that fixes any order issues.  (But I'm to lazy to test) :/

Comment: Corrected one typo and tested it because it is too hot for lawn work.  +1

Comment: The query will *repeat* `col1` field as many times as the count of records having the corresponding `col1` value, like `A 1 A 2 ..`. I *think* this is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos -- Good point -- I added in the DISTINCT I was missing

Answer (score 3):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col1 AS Col2, 0 AS grp
   FROM mytable

   UNION ALL

   SELECT Col2 AS Col1, Col1 AS Col2, 1 AS grp
   FROM mytable) AS t
ORDER BY Col2, grp, Col1
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/QCHAX96931)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to do a UNION, UNION ALL or reference the table more than once to unpivot data...

```
-- if Col2 is always a well ordered sequense like the test data...
SELECT 
    Col1 = x.Value
FROM 
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (IIF(td.Col2 = 1, td.Col1, NULL)), (CAST(td.Col2 AS CHAR(1))) ) x (Value)
WHERE
    x.Value IS NOT NULL;

-- if it isn't...
WITH 
    cre_Add_RN AS (
        SELECT 
            td.Col1,
            td.Col2,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.Col1 ORDER BY td.Col2)
        FROM 
            #TestData td
        )
SELECT 
    x.Value
FROM 
    cre_Add_RN arn
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (IIF(arn.RN = 1, arn.Col1, NULL)), (CAST(arn.Col2 AS CHAR(1))) ) x (Value)
WHERE 
    x.Value IS NOT NULL;
```

HTH,
Jason

Comment: This will *repeat* `Col1` value like: `A 1 A 2 ..`

Comment: Ahhh... Good catch! I missed the part where the Col1 isn't repeated... I'll post a fix in a sec...

Comment: This is great @JasonA.Long -- I'm just wondering why you imply `CROSS APPLY` is better than `UNION ALL` (which I don't think it is.)

Comment: A single pass over the base table will be far more efficient than multiple passes over the base table.